# how long does it take to confirm?

Tags: transactions

I am running bitcoin core latest. It is all caught up, so I know I have it in my wallet.

bitquick.co says the coin I sent them is unconfirmed 24 hrs now.... I used default fees... No clue there.

What do I do?

1) wait a week?
2) if i accidentally lowballed the fee, is it a dead-fish, or slow-mover??
3) wait xxx months for it to return to my wallet?
4) https://blockchain.info/address Should I click on one the 4 buttons on that page?

Thanks for any leads.

Comment: The provided link 404's for me.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, assuming you have a valid transaction ID (it wasn't clear from the link above), it may be best to wait until the transaction is confirmed.

You could also reach out to the support team associated with your wallet provider in the interim, let them know the issue, and ask if they have a replace by fee option available to help you.

Comment: replace by fee is executed by the sender, not the recipient, if jim didn't send with rbf enabled, he cannot rbf the transaction. He could try to doublespend it though. The recipient may use "child pays for parent".